# OS X installation duration?

Tags: macos, install

I bought a 2012 Macbook Pro and wanted a fresh install, So I booted while holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and did a fresh install after clearing the HDD via the setup. After the install I gave my credentials. Now I've been stuck for 80 minutes at a screen saying *"Configuring your Mac"*. It has a HDD so I understand it's not as fast as an SSD. This is my first time on OS X setup.

Is considered normal and should I just continue to wait?

[image: booting machine]

Comment: One shouldn't install OS X on a Mac mounted upside down. That confuses the post-flight script! ;-)

Comment: @klanomath haha sorry made the picture on my phone and it looked normal on my phone. tryd to reupload it after flipping but it keeps going this way up. 40 minutes in already regret im trying osx. Jk but bad first impression.

Comment: It may take up to 50-60 minutes. An upgrade on a Mac with a lot of small files (e.g. a developer machine or brew/MacPorts installed) may take even longer

Comment: @klanomath its a clean install (erased the drives content) i really have no idea what it should configure.

Comment: When reinstalling from recovery mode, it needs to download the full installer (about 5 GB IIRC), so depending in your internet connection that can certainly take a while. But I'm not sure if that's what's happening when it displays the "Configuring..." screen.

Comment: @gordondavisson this screen came after downloading and putting in my apple id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a hard power off (holding the power down button for a few secondss) and powered it on again. It all works fine now.